# C# Rental Program

Tags: c#, beginner, mvc, controller

I knew a little Java, and thought what the hell, I'll help my school and design this program that'll help checkout phone chargers and calculators and things to students. So I got in way over my head, but I got the program working. I wrote it in C#, and while the whole thing needs review, I really feel my checkout function could use immediate improvement.

This is the controller function for creating a checkout record, I have 6 different tables:

- `tb_BannedUsersTable`
- `tb_CheckoutCheckin`
- `tb_Items`
- `tb_LabTech` (employees)
- `tb_Student`

It starts by taking a Student ID and up-to 3 items from an HTML view to create a record. it creates a new record per item, because of how everything gets checked in. It's a long garbled mess, so any advice is greatly appreciated.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(string StudentID, string upc, string upc1, string upc2)
{
    try
    {
        ViewModels view = new ViewModels();
        Student_Entities ExternalDB = new Students_Entities();
        tb_Student sfh = new tb_Student();

        if (StudentID.Length > 9)
        {
            //Shortens the scanned StudentID to 9 characters
            StudentID = StudentID.Truncate(9);

        }

        // Checks for Student record in the exsisting database

        var queryCount = db.tb_Student.Where(s => s.ID == StudentID).Count();

        if (queryCount < 1)
        {
            // checks external database of students
            try
            {
                var bsh = ExternalDB.v_View.FirstOrDefault(s => s.ID == StudentID);
                if (bsh == null)
                {
                    ViewBag.Message = "Student ID # not found in the system, please add the student from the Home menu";
                    return View("Index");
                }
                //creates student record if its found
                sfh.ID = bsh.ID;
                sfh.EMAIL_ADDRESS = bsh.EMAIL_ADDRESS;
                sfh.UserNAME = bsh.UserNAME;
                sfh.FIRST_NAME = bsh.FIRST_NAME;
                sfh.LAST_NAME = bsh.LAST_NAME;
                sfh.PHONE = bsh.LAST_NAME;
                sfh.SIGNEDWAIVER = null;
                db.tb_Student.Add(sfh);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Student ID # not found in the system, please add the student from the Home menu";
                return View("Index");
            }
        }

        var tbs = db.tb_Student.FirstOrDefault(s => s.ID == StudentID);
        bool? x = tbs.SIGNEDWAIVER;

        //Checks for signed Waiver
        //Stores SessionVariables.
        if (x != true)
        {
            SessionVariables.waiverStudentId = StudentID;
            SessionVariables.waiverUPC = upc;
            SessionVariables.waiverUPC1 = upc1;
            SessionVariables.waiverUPC2 = upc2;
            ViewBag.Message = "Records indicate this user has not signed a waiver";
            return View("Waiver", tbs);
        }

        if (upc1 == "") { upc1 = null; }
        if (upc2 == "") { upc2 = null; }

        //checks for UPC Entry
        if (upc == null)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Item Number cannot be blank with checkout";
            return View("Index");
        }
        if (upc == upc1 || upc == upc2)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Item Number was the same in both fields";
            return View("Index");
        }

        //checks for banned users
        if (!view.isBannedUser(StudentID))
        {
            //user is good, check for vaild Items

            //Item 1 Check
            var itemCheckout = db.tb_Items.Where(s => s.ItemUPC == upc).FirstOrDefault();
            var checkedOut = db.tb_CheckoutCheckin.Where(s => s.ItemUPCFK == upc && s.CheckinDate == null).FirstOrDefault();
            if (itemCheckout == null)
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Item #1 " + upc + " number not found";
                return View("Index");
            }
            if (checkedOut != null)
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Our Records indicate that item" + upc + " is checked-out, please check the item in first! " + StudentID;
                return View("Index");
            }

            //Item 2 Check
            if (upc1 != null)
            {
                var itemCheckout1 = db.tb_Items.Where(s => s.ItemUPC == upc1).FirstOrDefault();
                var checkedOut1 = db.tb_CheckoutCheckin.Where(s => s.ItemUPCFK == upc1 && s.CheckinDate == null).FirstOrDefault();
                if (itemCheckout1 == null)
                {
                    ViewBag.Message = "Item #2 " + upc1 + " not found";
                    return View("Index");
                }
                if (checkedOut1 != null)
                {
                    ViewBag.Message = "Our Records indicate that item #2 " + upc1 + " is checked-out, please check the item in first! " + StudentID;
                    return View("Index");
                }
            }
            //Item 3 Check
            if (upc2 != null)
            {
                var itemCheckout2 = db.tb_LabInventoryItems.Where(s => s.ItemUPC == upc2).FirstOrDefault();
                var checkedOut2 = db.tb_CheckoutCheckin.Where(s => s.ItemUPCFK == upc2 && s.CheckinDate == null).FirstOrDefault();
                if (itemCheckout2 == null)
                {
                    ViewBag.Message = "Item #3 " + upc2 + " not found";
                    return View("Index");
                }
                if (checkedOut2 != null)
                {
                    ViewBag.Message = "Our Records indicate that item #3 " + upc2 + " is checked-out, please check the item in first! " + StudentID;
                    return View("Index");
                }
            }


            var checkoutRecord = new tb_CheckoutCheckin();
            var checkoutRecord1 = new tb_CheckoutCheckin();
            var checkoutRecord2 = new tb_CheckoutCheckin();

            var stuRec = db.tb_Student.FirstOrDefault(s => s.ID == StudentID);
            var stuFirst = stuRec.FIRST_NAME + " " + stuRec.LAST_NAME;


            //One item Checkout
            if (upc != null && StudentID != null && upc1 == null && upc2 == null)

            {
                checkoutRecord.Student_IDFK = StudentID;
                checkoutRecord.ItemUPCFK = upc;
                checkoutRecord.ItemIDFK = itemCheckout.ItemId;
                checkoutRecord.CheckoutLabTech = SessionVariables.CurrentUserId;
                checkoutRecord.CheckoutDate = DateTime.Now;
                db.tb_CheckoutCheckin.Add(checkoutRecord);
                db.SaveChanges();
                ModelState.Clear();
                var model = db.tb_CheckoutCheckin.Where(s => s.CheckinDate == null);
                ViewBag.Message = stuFirst + " " + upc + " due back at " + SessionVariables.ItemDueDateTime;
                return View("Index", model);
            }
            //two item Checkout
            if (upc != null && StudentID != null && upc1 != null && upc2 == null)
            {
                checkoutRecord.Student_IDFK = StudentID;
                checkoutRecord.ItemUPCFK = upc;
                checkoutRecord.ItemIDFK = itemCheckout.ItemId;
                checkoutRecord.CheckoutLabTech = SessionVariables.CurrentUserId;
                checkoutRecord.CheckoutDate = DateTime.Now;

                checkoutRecord1.Student_IDFK = StudentID;
                checkoutRecord1.ItemUPCFK = upc1;
                checkoutRecord1.ItemIDFK = itemCheckout.ItemId;
                checkoutRecord1.CheckoutLabTech = SessionVariables.CurrentUserId;
                checkoutRecord1.CheckoutDate = DateTime.Now;


                db.tb_CheckoutCheckin.Add(checkoutRecord);
                db.tb_CheckoutCheckin.Add(checkoutRecord1);
                db.SaveChanges();
                ModelState.Clear();
                var model = db.tb_CheckoutCheckin.Where(s => s.CheckinDate == null);
                ViewBag.Message = stuFirst + " " + upc + " and " + upc1 + " due back at " + SessionVariables.ItemDueDateTime;
                return View("Index", model);
            }
            //three item Checkout
            if (upc != null && StudentID != null && upc1 != null && upc2 != null)
            {
                checkoutRecord.Student_IDFK = StudentID;
                checkoutRecord.ItemUPCFK = upc;
                checkoutRecord.ItemIDFK = itemCheckout.ItemId;
                checkoutRecord.CheckoutLabTech = SessionVariables.CurrentUserId;
                checkoutRecord.CheckoutDate = DateTime.Now;

                checkoutRecord1.Student_IDFK = StudentID;
                checkoutRecord1.ItemUPCFK = upc1;
                checkoutRecord1.ItemIDFK = itemCheckout.ItemId;
                checkoutRecord1.CheckoutLabTech = SessionVariables.CurrentUserId;
                checkoutRecord1.CheckoutDate = DateTime.Now;

                checkoutRecord2.Student_IDFK = StudentID;
                checkoutRecord2.ItemUPCFK = upc2;
                checkoutRecord2.ItemIDFK = itemCheckout.ItemId;
                checkoutRecord2.CheckoutLabTech = SessionVariables.CurrentUserId;
                checkoutRecord2.CheckoutDate = DateTime.Now;


                db.tb_CheckoutCheckin.Add(checkoutRecord);
                db.tb_CheckoutCheckin.Add(checkoutRecord1);
                db.tb_CheckoutCheckin.Add(checkoutRecord2);
                db.SaveChanges();
                ModelState.Clear();
                var model = db.tb_CSUCheckoutCheckin.Where(s => s.CheckinDate == null);
                ViewBag.Message = stuFirst + " " + upc + " and " + upc1 + " and " + upc2 + " due back at " + SessionVariables.ItemDueDateTime;
                return View("Index", model);
            }

        }
        ViewBag.Message = "That user has been banned from checkout! Or you got this page in error, try again. " + StudentID;
        return View("Index");

    }
    catch
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "An error occured during Checkout, please try again, Student Id." + StudentID;
        return View("Index");
    }
}

// GET: tb_Checkout/Edit/5
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    tb_CSUCheckoutCheckin tb_CSUCheckoutCheckin = db.tb_CSUCheckoutCheckin.Find(id);
    if (tb_CSUCheckoutCheckin == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(tb_CSUCheckoutCheckin);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "CheckoutCheckinId,CSU_IDFK,ItemUPCFK,CheckoutLabTech,CheckoutDate,CheckinLabTech,CheckinDate,CheckoutLocationFK,CheckinLocationFK")] tb_CSUCheckoutCheckin tb_CSUCheckoutCheckin)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(tb_CSUCheckoutCheckin).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(tb_CSUCheckoutCheckin);
}

//alter record for waiver signed
public ActionResult WaiverSign(string id)
{
    var v = db.tb_Student.FirstOrDefault(s => s.CSU_ID == id);
    v.SIGNEDWAIVER = true;
    db.Entry(v).State = EntityState.Modified;
    ViewBag.Message = "Waiver Recorded, and Checkout Complete!";
    return Create(SessionVariables.waiverStudnetID, SessionVariables.waiverUPC, SessionVariables.waiverUPC1, SessionVariables.waiverUPC2);
}
```

I figure there has got to be a more efficient way to handle all this, and I'm not really sure how to create a 'data access layer' and I'm probably breaking some security rules, so the more help the better. My `Checkin` function isn't any better.

Comment: Out of curiosity why C# if you already knew Java?

Comment: It was requested by my Boss, and I only knew a little Java.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Disclaimer: if this answer feels like it gets less patient and more "to-the-point" as it goes on, I'm *really* tired as I am / was writing this and I can't English / logic right now. I promise I mean the very best with this, and I'm having trouble even typing at the moment. This is actually *fairly solid* code for a C# beginner.

---

Oh boy, there's a lot to talk about here.

Good news is we have plenty of time.

First: you variable naming is not the greatest. I.e. `tbs` is not self-explanatory, `student` is. I'm not going to comment on the names of the properties (or fields if you're into that) of the types, since you didn't post the definitions. But if you add a new question with the type definitions I promise I'll be just as brutal (but in a good way) on them as I was on this code. :)

---

> ```
>     ViewModels view = new ViewModels();
>     Student_Entities ExternalDB = new Students_Entities();
>     tb_Student sfh = new tb_Student();
>
>     if (StudentID.Length > 9)
>     {
>         //Shortens the scanned StudentID to 9 characters
>         StudentID = StudentID.Truncate(9);
>
>     }
>
>     // Checks for Student record in the exsisting database
>
>     var queryCount = db.tb_Student.Where(s => s.ID == StudentID).Count();
>
>     if (queryCount < 1)
>     {
>         // checks external database of students
>         try
>         {
>             var bsh = ExternalDB.v_View.FirstOrDefault(s => s.ID == StudentID);
>             if (bsh == null)
>             {
>                 ViewBag.Message = "Student ID # not found in the system, please add the student from the Home menu";
>                 return View("Index");
>             }
>             //creates student record if its found
>             sfh.ID = bsh.ID;
>             sfh.EMAIL_ADDRESS = bsh.EMAIL_ADDRESS;
>             sfh.UserNAME = bsh.UserNAME;
>             sfh.FIRST_NAME = bsh.FIRST_NAME;
>             sfh.LAST_NAME = bsh.LAST_NAME;
>             sfh.PHONE = bsh.LAST_NAME;
>             sfh.SIGNEDWAIVER = null;
>             db.tb_Student.Add(sfh);
>             db.SaveChanges();
>         }
>         catch
>         {
>             ViewBag.Message = "Student ID # not found in the system, please add the student from the Home menu";
>             return View("Index");
>         }
>     }
>
>     var tbs = db.tb_Student.FirstOrDefault(s => s.ID == StudentID);
> ```

We're going to start with this block as it made me the least happy when I saw it.

There are four glaring issues here:

1. You search `db.tb_Student` twice, guaranteed.
2. You use `.Count()` to check if it exists.
3. You wrap a significant amount of work in a `try`/`catch` block, that doesn't need to be.
4. You treat `sfh` *really* weirdly.

Obviously we want to cut down on the work we do, always. I'm going to assume that `tb_Student` is a class. In this case, we can immediately reduce a lot of the work we do right off the bat.

```
var tbs = db.tb_Student.FirstOrDefault(s => s.ID == StudentID);
```

We're going to put this *before* our `if` statement, since C# and EF behave in a **very predictable** way. If there is no `tb_Student` record matching the ID, `tbs` will be null. We're going to modify our `if` to account for that.

```
if (tbs == null)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

I don't see you using `sfh` anywhere other than that if, so move that declaration *inside* the `if` block.

```
    if (tbs == null)
    {
        var bsh = ExternalDB.v_View.FirstOrDefault(s => s.ID == StudentID);
        if (bsh == null)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Student ID # not found in the system, please add the student from the Home menu";
            return View("Index");
        }
        //creates student record if its found
        var sfh = new tb_Student();
        sfh.ID = bsh.ID;
        sfh.EMAIL_ADDRESS = bsh.EMAIL_ADDRESS;
        sfh.UserNAME = bsh.UserNAME;
        sfh.FIRST_NAME = bsh.FIRST_NAME;
        sfh.LAST_NAME = bsh.LAST_NAME;
        sfh.PHONE = bsh.LAST_NAME;
        sfh.SIGNEDWAIVER = null;
        db.tb_Student.Add(sfh);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Next you can pull a lot of that work outside the `try` block, and throw a better error. I would, at the very least, change it so that the error message reads "Could not migrate Student ID" et. al.

Then, at the end of that block (after `db.SaveChanges()`), if you *really* want, you could add another `tbs = ...`, or just `tbs = sfh;` since they're the same type and such.

After we adjust this section, we should extract a method for it.

```
private tb_Student GetOrMigrateStudent(int studentId)
{
    Student_Entities ExternalDB = new Students_Entities();
    var tbs = db.tb_Student.FirstOrDefault(s => s.ID == StudentID);

    if (tbs == null)
    {
        var bsh = ExternalDB.v_View.FirstOrDefault(s => s.ID == StudentID);

        if (bsh == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("studentId", "Student ID # not found in the system, please add the student from the Home menu");\
        }

        //creates student record if its found
        var sfh = new tb_Student();
        sfh.ID = bsh.ID;
        sfh.EMAIL_ADDRESS = bsh.EMAIL_ADDRESS;
        sfh.UserNAME = bsh.UserNAME;
        sfh.FIRST_NAME = bsh.FIRST_NAME;
        sfh.LAST_NAME = bsh.LAST_NAME;
        sfh.PHONE = bsh.LAST_NAME;
        sfh.SIGNEDWAIVER = null;
        db.tb_Student.Add(sfh);
        db.SaveChanges();

        tbs = sfh;
    }

    return tbs;
}
```

This may need a little cleanup/adapting on your end.

---

Ok, so now our code looks like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(string StudentID, string upc, string upc1, string upc2)
{
    try
    {
        ViewModels view = new ViewModels();

        if (StudentID.Length > 9)
        {
            //Shortens the scanned StudentID to 9 characters
            StudentID = StudentID.Truncate(9);
        }

        var tbs = GetOrMigrateStudent(StudentId);

        ...
    }
}
```

The next block to examine is:

> ```
> bool? x = tbs.SIGNEDWAIVER;
>
> //Checks for signed Waiver
> //Stores SessionVariables.
> if (x != true)
> {
>     SessionVariables.waiverStudentId = StudentID;
>     SessionVariables.waiverUPC = upc;
>     SessionVariables.waiverUPC1 = upc1;
>     SessionVariables.waiverUPC2 = upc2;
>     ViewBag.Message = "Records indicate this user has not signed a waiver";
>     return View("Waiver", tbs);
> }
> ```

This can be cleaned an extracted pretty quick.

```
public bool MustSignWaiver(tb_Student student)
{
    return student.SIGNEDWAIVER != true;
}
```

We do this so that we can simply call `MustSignWaiver(tbs)` instead of declaring our `x` and whatnot. We end up with:

```
if (MustSignWaiver(tbs))
{
    SessionVariables.waiverStudentId = StudentID;
    SessionVariables.waiverUPC = upc;
    SessionVariables.waiverUPC1 = upc1;
    SessionVariables.waiverUPC2 = upc2;
    ViewBag.Message = "Records indicate this user has not signed a waiver";
    return View("Waiver", tbs);
}
```

This makes things much more verbose. We no longer need the comments (the code explains itself).

---

Next we'll look at:

> ```
>     if (upc1 == "") { upc1 = null; }
>     if (upc2 == "") { upc2 = null; }
>
>     //checks for UPC Entry
>     if (upc == null)
>     {
>         ViewBag.Message = "Item Number cannot be blank with checkout";
>         return View("Index");
>     }
>     if (upc == upc1 || upc == upc2)
>     {
>         ViewBag.Message = "Item Number was the same in both fields";
>         return View("Index");
>     }
> ```

This actually presents an interesting bug: what happens when I fill `upc1` but not `upc`? Well we can fix that pretty easily.

```
var upcs = new List<string>();
upcs.Add(upc);
upcs.Add(upc1);
upcs.Add(upc2);
upcs = upcs.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).ToList();
```

And now we forget about `upc`, `upc1` and `upc2` for the rest of the code. We'll do it with LINQ.

```
if (upcs.Length == 0)
{
    // No valid UPCs
}

if (upcs.Distinct() != upcs.Length)
{
    // Duplicate found
}
```

This got longer, but it got more usable later (you'll see how). Next we'll extract it to a method.

```
public List<string> GetValidUpcs(params string[] upcs)
{
    var result = new List<string>();

    result.AddRange(upcs);
    result = result.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).ToList();

    return result;
}
```

And in our method we just do `var upcs = GetValidUpcs(upc, upc1, upc2);`. All the heavy lifting is now extracted, and if we add a new UPC it's trivial to add it. (Add a parameter to our `ActionResult` method, and pass the value to `GetValidUpcs`.)

---

We're going to look at just a couple lines next:

> ```
> if (!view.isBannedUser(StudentID))
> {
>     ...
> }
> ViewBag.Message = "That user has been banned from checkout! Or you got this page in error, try again. " + StudentID;
> return View("Index");
> ```

You know what this looks like it needs? Just a quick reorder.

```
if (view.isBannedUser(StudentId))
{
    ViewBag.Message = "That user has been banned from checkout! Or you got this page in error, try again. " + StudentID;
    return View("Index");
}
...
```

We want to reduce nested stuff (a.k.a. arrow code).

---

Next we have:

> ```
> var itemCheckout = db.tb_Items.Where(s => s.ItemUPC == upc).FirstOrDefault();
> ```

You put your predicate in `FirstOrDefault` above, so you know it accepts one here. No need for `Where`.

```
var itemCheckout = db.tb_Items.FirstOrDefault(s => s.ItemUPC == upc);
```

Of course, we can checkout all the items from `upcs` now with some LINQ.

```
foreach (var upc in upcs)
{
    var itemCheckout = db.tb_Items.FirstOrDefault(s => s.ItemUPC == upc);
    var checkedOut = db.tb_CheckoutCheckin.FirstOrDefault(s => s.ItemUPCFK == upc && s.CheckinDate == null);

    // Conditions/view update here.
}
```

---

Ok, so we've taken a lot of this down and cleaned it, just a little bit further to go.

First, `StudentID` should not be null here. So remove that check altogether.

> ```
> var stuRec = db.tb_Student.FirstOrDefault(s => s.ID == StudentID);
> ```

Second, what are you using a new DB query for? Does `tbs` not have our student already?

Next, you can write one abstraction now that we have `upcs` in a list instead of having to write an `if` block for each combination.

```
var stuFirst = tbs.FIRST_NAME + " " + tbs.LAST_NAME;
var checkoutDateTime = DateTime.Now;

foreach (var upc in upcs)
{
    var checkoutRecord = new tb_CheckoutCheckin();
    var itemCheckout = db.tb_Items.Where(s => s.ItemUPC == upc).FirstOrDefault();
    checkoutRecord.Student_IDFK = StudentID;
    checkoutRecord.ItemUPCFK = upc;
    checkoutRecord.ItemIDFK = itemCheckout.ItemId;
    checkoutRecord.CheckoutLabTech = SessionVariables.CurrentUserId;
    checkoutRecord.CheckoutDate = checkoutDateTime;
    db.tb_CheckoutCheckin.Add(checkoutRecord);
}

db.SaveChanges();
ModelState.Clear();
var model = db.tb_CSUCheckoutCheckin.Where(s => s.CheckinDate == null);
```

Lastly, we'll `string.Join` on our `upcs` since we want to be dynamice with it.

```
ViewBag.Message = stuFirst + " " + string.Join(" and ", upcs) + " due back at " + SessionVariables.ItemDueDateTime;
return View("Index", model);
```

---

And we're done with this method! :) I'm not going to comment on the others, they're not nearly as big of a mess, and you should be able to take a lot of what we learned from here to them. I wrote this entire thing outside an IDE and I'm a little tired at the moment, I'll try to clean this up more when I wake up.

Overall, not bad for coming from [java](/questions/tagged/java). Hopefully you learned something from all of this. I mean it all in the best of spirits. :)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain all this to me. I greatly appreciate it. I learned quite a bit. Just so I understand correctly, when you say 'extract a method from it' that method should be stored in a model rather than a controller?

Comment: @JohnRussell No problem, that's what Code Review is for. :) As far as method extraction: it should be placed *wherever it is appropriate*. If it only has a use on the one `Controller`, keep it in the controller. If it has a use on the `Model` itself, put it on the model. Basically, ask yourself: if I need this again, where will it make *most* sense?